# Did I crash this Unix server?

Tags: unix, visual-studio-code

I was making a custom shell for my assignment on my univ class server. but it got caught in an infinite loop and VS code is now unresponsive. Now when I log on in putty, it says:

```
-bash: fork: retry: no child process (it says this for a few times)
-bash: fork: retry: resource temporarily unavailable.
```

Did I brick the system? What do I do? CTRL + c doesn't work because I disabled it with `signal()`;

Comment: Why disable things like ctrl+c ?

Comment: @SolarMike It was one of our requirements on the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to open the management console (in case you have access to it), from there open a terminal to your server and kill the code you are running now (as a `root` user, `kill -9` should definitely do the trick).

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have access to both the console and a root user account. I sent a message to my professor, so he will probably do that when he sees it. So there's absolutely nothing i can do right now?

Comment: Not that I know of. You might try using SecureCRT as a terminal, but I doubt this will solve your problem. On the other hand, if it's part of the assignment to disable "Ctrl+c", then I assume that your teacher has foreseen some way to handle this issue.